# How to create a new conduit producing input and output

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am finding such a Conduit function to produce both input and output

```
pairConduit :: (Monad m) => ConduitM i o m r -> ConduitM i (i, o) m r
```

I got a wrong solution:

```
pairConduit :: (Monad m) => ConduitM i o m () -> ConduitM i (i, o) m ()
pairConduit c = do
    mb <- await
    case mb of
        (Just i) -> do 
             mapOutput (\a -> (i,a)) c
        Nothing -> return ()
```

Comment: Conduits can consume several inputs to produce one output. What should `pairConduit` do in that situation?

Comment: Good Point! It seems conduit should not be used in that way.